# MAUI Android - context?

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

I'm migrating my Xamarin.Android app to MAUI. On another SO someone mentioned that PackageManager needs to be replaced. So I changed the code from:

```
var component = new ComponentName(this, this.Class);
var activityInfo = PackageManager.GetActivityInfo(component, 0);
```

To:

```
var myCrrentActivity = MauiApplication.Current.GetActivity();
var component = new ComponentName(myCrrentActivity, myCrrentActivity.Class);
```

However the MauiApplication.Current.GetActivity() does not work. It is null by the time it gets to the next line. I have tried applying this in different Activities with the same result.

This is in my BaseActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "BaseActivity")]
public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity, ISessionExpired, IPBottomNavBarIcon
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and buy Maui you mean .NET Maui cross-platform then to get the current activity you need to look into the ApplicationModel's Platform clas

```
var currentActivity = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity
```